# What's the proper idiom for short-circuiting a Ruby `begin ... end` block?

Tags: ruby, memoization

I often memoize Ruby methods using the `begin ... end` block syntax:

```
$memo = {}
def calculate(something)
  $memo[something] ||= begin
    perform_calculation(something)
  end
end
```

However, there's a gotcha here. If I return early from the `begin ... end` block via a guard clause, the result is not memoized:

```
$memo = {}
def calculate(something)
  $memo[something] ||= begin
    return 'foo' if something == 'bar'
    perform_calculation(something)
  end
end
# does not memoize 'bar'; method will be run each time
```

I can avoid this by avoiding the `return` statement:

```
$memo = {}
def calculate(something)
  $memo[something] ||= begin
    if something == 'bar'
      'foo'
    else
      perform_calculation(something)
    end
  end
end
```

This works, but I don't love it because:

1. it's easy to forget I'm not allowed to use `return` in this case.
2. with many conditions it clutters up the code as opposed to the guard clause.

Is there a better idiom for this besides just avoiding `return`?

Comment: A good article on some conventions: http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/4-simple-memoization-patterns-in-ruby-and-one-gem//

Comment: I'd **strongly** advise against using globals for caching. It's important to keep your variables contextual, that is use `@`-style instance variables whenever possible.

Comment: if your program has pure functions, you can take it a step further and cache method calls themselves. For example [cache-method](https://github.com/seamusabshere/cache_method). A benefit of having a discrete API for the cache is that it's easier to switch out the persistence type, if desired.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, begin...end  cannot be short-circuited. You can do exactly what you're trying to do with procs though:

```
$memo = {}
def calculate(something)
  $memo[something] ||= -> do
    return 'foo' if something == 'bar'
    perform_calculation(something)
  end.call
end
```

That being said, I've never seen this done before, so it's certainly not idiomatic.

Answer (score 4):

I'd add another layer:

```
def calculate(something)
  $memo[something] ||= _calculate(something)
end

def _calculate(something)
  return if something == 'bar'
  perform_calculation(something) # or maybe inline this then
end
```

This has the additional benefit of providing you with a method you could call whenever you want to be sure to get a freshly computed result. I would spend some more time on the method naming though.

Answer (score 2):

One way to tackle this is with meta-programming where you wrap the method after it's defined. This preserves any behaviour in it:

```
def memoize(method_name)
  implementation = method(method_name)

  cache = Hash.new do |h, k|
    h[k] = implementation.call(*k)
  end

  define_method(method_name) do |*args|
    cache[args]
  end
end
```

This creates a closure variable which acts as a cache. That avoids the ugly global, but it also means you can't really clear out that cache if you need to, so if you pass in a large number of different arguments it could end up consuming a lot of memory. Be cautious! That functionality could be added if necessary by defining some auxiliary method like `x_forget` for any given method `x`.

Here's how it works:

```
def calculate(n)
  return n if (n < 1)

  n + 2
end
memoize(:calculate)
```

Then you can see:

```
10.times do |i|
  p '%d=%d' % [ i % 5, calculate(i % 5) ]
end

# => "0=0"
# => "1=3"
# => "2=4"
# => "3=5"
# => "4=6"
# => "0=0"
# => "1=3"
# => "2=4"
# => "3=5"
# => "4=6"
```

Comment: Very interesting! Presumably it's in a module to be included.

Comment: @CarySwoveland It's a rehash of the old `memoize` method that was in Rails. RIP.

Answer (score 0):

I fear I don't understand the question correctly, as it would seem something quite simple would do.

```
$memo = {}

def calculate(something)
  $memo[something] ||= something == 'bar' ? 'foo' : perform_calculation(something)
end
```

Let's try it.

```
def perform_calculation(something)
  'baz'
end

calculate('bar')
  #=> "foo" 
$memo
  #=> {"bar"=>"foo"} 
calculate('baz')
  #=> "baz" 
$memo
  #=> {"bar"=>"foo", "baz"=>"baz"} 
calculate('bar')
  #=> "foo" 
$memo
  #=> {"bar"=>"foo", "baz"=>"baz"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a solution using `return` but for the guard clause in your example I would use `case`.

```
$memo = {}
def calculate(something)
  $memo[something] ||= case something
                       when 'foo' then 'bar'
                       else perform_calculation(something)
                       end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `break` statements in a `#tap` block:

```rb
def val
  @val ||= default.tap do
    break val1 if cond1
    break val2 if cond2
    break val3 if cond3
  end
end
```

You could also use 1.6's `#then` or 1.5's `#yield_self`, but then don't forget to return the default value at the end of the block, or it'll default to `nil`. In your example it's not a problem since the default is only evaluated at the end:

```rb
def calculate(something)
  @calculate ||= {}
  return @calculate[something] if @calculate.key?(something)

  @calculate[something] = something.then do |something|
    break 'foo' if something == 'bar'
    perform_calculation(something)
  end
end
```